# Mac OS X sharing, not working

Tags: macbook, network-shares

I'm using a Macbook with Snow Leopard and my roommates are using the same macbooks too and we can't get the sharing to work.

I've checked the sharing settings under preferences and I've followed the help from Apple.com. Everything seems to be configured correctly. I've even used Bonjour to see if that might show the others on the network but nothing. Also, the firewall is turned off.

We're on the same wifi network.

What could I be missing that won't make it work?

Also, under iTunes, the computers used to show up but they haven't even showed up on there for home sharing.

What's the best way I can troubleshoot this?

**Edit:** I'm on a home network, with 5 computers connected. There's 3 macbooks and 2 windows laptops,  but this isn't really about the PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set points to share and users who can access these shares.

Bonjour is only going to work well if you are all on the same subdomain.  You didn't say if you are on a large wireless network (campus) or small (apt/house).

Try to connect through IP.

You can first try to ping the other computers.  If you get a response, then try to connect to server afp or smb://ipaddress and see if the shares show up (based on what you enabled), but first and foremost, make sure your shares are set up properly with share points and users who can access them.

Comment: Set points = shared folders? It's on a home/small network with 3 macbooks & 2 pcs (disregard the PCs in this situation).

Comment: Yes, shared folders (bad grammar on my part).  Unless you are just looking for the default Public folder for each user, which you should see if all are on the same subnet and file sharing is turned on on all machines.  Verify that in Finder Preferences Shared and Bonjour computers are checked to be visible.